# Creating new nested model in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i am pretty new in RoR and trying to understand the basics. I have two models

```
class Beekeeper < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :apiaries, dependent: :destroy 
end
```

and

```
class Apiary < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :beekeeper
end
```

The controller for the Beekeepers is working just fine, but i have trouble routing to the 'new' route for apiary creation.

The apiaries controller is

```
class ApiariesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @beekeeper = Beekeeper.find(params[:beekeeper_id] )
    @apiary = @beekeeper.apiaries.build
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render new }
    end
  end


  private

    def apiary_params
      params.require(:apiary).permit(:name, :location, :numberofbeehives, :beekeeper_id)
    end
end
```

Also in beekeepers controller we have a

```
def current_beekeeper
  @current_beekeeper ||= Beekeeper.find_by(id: session[:beekeeper_id])
end
```

I am using 'application.html.erb' for rendering a header and a footer in all pages. The first problem is in the '_header.html.erb':

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <li><%= link_to "Insert Apiary", new_beekeeper_apiary_path(@beekeeper) %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "All Beekeepers", beekeepers_path %></li>

  <li><%= link_to "Profile", beekeeper_path(@beekeeper) %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
  <li>
    <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If in the links for 'profile' and 'new_apiary' i include (@beekeeper) i get a:
        $`No route matches {:action=>"new", :beekeeper_id=>nil, :controller=>"apiaries"} missing required keys: [:beekeeper_id]`$

If in the above links i include instead of $`@beekeeper`$ -> $`current_beekeeper`$ (or just current_beekeeper dunno why) the pages load just fine but then when i click on the new apiary link i get either (Couldn't find Beekeeper with 'id'=) if i use  $ `@beekeeper = Beekeeper.find(params[:id] )`
in my apiaries controller or a stack too deep error (it is recursing around lines 4 and 5 of the controller) if i use $ `@beekeeper = Beekeeper.find(params[:beekeeper_id] )`$ which i think should work.

Forgot to mention my routes files is

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :beekeepers do
    resources :apiaries
  end
end
```

and i do have a beekeeper_id field in my apiaries db.
Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to troubleshoot without seeing the action you're going through to get to that error, but in your header, you should be invoking the *current_beekeeper* method for it's return value.

You already have logic to check if the beekeeper is logged in before showing your header so it is assumed that *session[:beekeeper_id]* is not nil. By invoking the *current_beekeeper* method, you'll be able to get the current beekeeper object.

If you depend on the @beekeeper instance variable, it's not always guaranteed to be set depending on the controller action that renders your view.